# Android: soft keyboard pushes up whole layout, need to resize the listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a full screen chat layout where I have a header with a logo on the top, then follows a listView with all chat messages and at the bottom I have the editText and the buttom to send the chat message. Now what happens when I click in the editText is, that the whole layout gets pushed up. What I need is, the header with the logo to always stay where they are and the listView to gets resized.

this does not do the trick:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

this neither:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

maybe because I have a full screen layout?

I need to find a different way to resize my listView once a keyboard is present, any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Here is my layout

```
<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ss99_yellow_area_navigation_bar"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ss99_button_back" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ss99_logo_small" />

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ss9_yellow_bar_chat_new" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userOpponent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/userOpponent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/userOpponent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/chatList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        android:listSelector="#00000000" 
     android:layout_weight="1"
      android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll">
    </ListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ss9_yellow_area_for_bottom_and_chat_string" >

           <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/field1"
                    android:layout_width="220dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/ss1_field_big" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/chatEdit"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/field1"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/field1"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/field1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >

                </EditText>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chatOk"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        android:src="@drawable/ss4_button_go_small" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add your Layout in scrollview

Comment: already thought of that but my layout has a listview, listvies and scrollviews dont play nice together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

okay so I actually solved this myself, but I think this is not more than a hack so I might be revisit this at a later point. but the point is it works (tested this on a Galaxy S4)

I resize my listView according to the height of the displayed softKeyboard and resize it back once the keyboard is gone.

```
private static boolean keyboardHidden = true;
private static int reduceHeight = 0;
//...
//...
final View decorView = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        decorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);

        int displayHeight = rect.bottom - rect.top;
        int height = decorView.getHeight();
        boolean keyboardHiddenTemp = (double)displayHeight / height > 0.8 ;
        int mylistviewHeight = mylistview.getMeasuredHeight();

        if (keyboardHiddenTemp != keyboardHidden) {                 
            keyboardHidden = keyboardHiddenTemp;

            if (!keyboardHidden) {      

                reduceHeight = height - displayHeight;

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams mParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,mylistviewHeight - reduceHeight); 
                mylistview.setLayoutParams(mParam);
                mylistview.requestLayout();

            } else {

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams mParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,mylistviewHeight + reduceHeight); 
                mylistview.setLayoutParams(mParam);
                mylistview.requestLayout();


            }
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: it flies way to far off the screen

Answer (score 5):

Try to add this to your activity in Manifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustNothing">  
 </activity>
```

Comment: not the desired effect, the layout remained at its position but now the keyboard is always visible and overlapping the editText. you can not see what you are typing

Comment: Is it possible to get the keyboard height by using `adjustNothing` in the manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your activity

```
<activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
</activity>
```

But for this to effect put the height of listview `fill_parent`